# Is this good design?

Tags: c#, oop

I am creating a text editor.  My text-box control is a subclass of `TextBox` called `Editor`.  My main form, `MainForm`, has an instance of `Editor`.

When MainForm wants to, say, load a text document, it calls `Editor.LoadDocument(string path)`.  `Editor.LoadDocument` calls `Document.Load(string path)`.

The same kind of thing happens with save:  `MainForm --> Editor.SaveDocument --> Document.Save`.

It seems that `Editor` is acting as a middleman unnecessarily here, so I'm thinking of just letting `MainForm` access `Document` directly:  `editor.Document.Load(path)`.  `Editor` would still create and maintain `Document`; it would just provide direct access to it.

Note that this would create a bidirectional association:  `Editor` would have a `Document` and `Document` would have an `Editor` (`Document` uses `Editor.Text` and subscribes to `Editor.TextChanged`).

I have two questions:

1. Is this good design?
2. Do bidirectional associations create any slowdown pertaining to garbage collection when the app exits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read about patterns such as Model-View-Controller.

Generally, the UI should activate operations directly on the model (`Document` in your case), and then the view (`Editor`) should be subscribed to events and act as an observer.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that this will work, because Document subscribes to Editor.TextChanged, and Document sets its Modified to true when the text is changed.  I will look into MVC in any case.  Thanks.

Comment: @Tom: Where is the content stored?  It sounds like you `Editor` has responsibilities of model and view intermingled.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to let the editor handle it's editor tasks.

A better way of communicating back to the main form soul be to create events in the editor that the main form can then subscribe to

As far as garbage collection goes, if controls are referencing each other just maker sure when you want to get rid of them that you actually can get rid if both and do get rid of both.